# Is there any way to prevent committing to a local git branch?

Tags: git

I know on various git hosting sites you can make a policy that you can't push directly to a certain branch and instead need to make a pull request - is there any way on my local repo to make sure I can't commit to those branches as well? I keep finding myself forgetting to make a feature branch, committing changes to the main branch (development, master, whatever), and having to cherry pick them out and reset or reclone in order to get my local branch in sync with the server.

Answer (score 3):

I do that all the time.  You don't have to go through all that trouble to fix it.  Say I am on branch `develop` and commit to it by mistake.  All I have to is create the feature branch I should have created before:

```
git checkout -b myfeature
```

Then, since I haven't pushed `develop`, I can simply delete my local `develop` branch:

```
git branch -d develop
```

That's it! It's all sorted, as if I had created the branch before I did the commit.

Your new `myfeature` branch already has the commit you made and `origin/develop` does not, since you never pushed `develop`.  It's exactly as you want it.

The next time you do

```
git checkout develop
```

you will be at the commit before your `myfeature` branch, since `git` will place `develop` at `origin/develop`.

There is no need to prevent yourself from committing to your local `develop`.  This "mistake" is so easy to fix, I don't even consider a mistake.  It doesn't really matter either way to me whether I create my feature branch before or after I commit.

<soapbox>Take some time to learn how `git` really works.  There are tons of tutorials.  Don't just stop with the bare minimum of knowledge.  It will save you *tons* of time over the long run.</soapbox>